# Flat datastructure vs multiple databases - NoSQL

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-design, nosql

Firebase documentation article [Structure Your Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure) section [Best practices for data structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure) says "Avoid nesting data".

What are the benefits for performance and maintenance to have several DBs vs a flat structure, or they will work same in average?

In SQL we create tables and then set relationships between them. In a NoSQL I can create several DBs and imitate that.

For example in a flat structure:

```
{
  "chatsId": [
    "some-chat-id-1",
    "some-chat-id-2",
    ...
  ],
  "chatsInfo": {
    "some-chat-id-1": {
      "between": [
         "some-user-id-1",
         "some-user-id-2"
       ],
       messages: "some-messages-id-1"
    },
    "some-chat-id-2": {
      "between": [
         "some-user-id-3",
         "some-user-id-4"
       ],
       messages: "some-messages-id-2"
    },
    ...
  },
  "messages": {
    "some-messages-id-1": [
      {
        ... some message data 1
      },
      {
        ... some message data 2
      },
      ...
    ],
    "some-messages-id-2": [
      {
        ... some message data 1
      },
      {
        ... some message data 2
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
}
```

But with multiple databases:

ChatsDB

```
{
  "chatsId": [
    "some-chat-id-1",
    "some-chat-id-2",
    ...
  ]
}
```

ChatsInfoDB

```
{
  "chatsInfo": {
    "some-chat-id-1": {
      "between": [
         "some-user-id-1",
         "some-user-id-2"
       ],
       messages: "some-messages-id-1"
    },
    "some-chat-id-2": {
      "between": [
         "some-user-id-3",
         "some-user-id-4"
       ],
       messages: "some-messages-id-2"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

MessagesDB

```
{
  "messages": {
    "some-messages-id-1": [
      {
        ... some message data 1
      },
      {
        ... some message data 2
      },
      ...
    ],
    "some-messages-id-2": [
      {
        ... some message data 1
      },
      {
        ... some message data 2
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? How are you stuck answering yourself? Yes or no questions are seldom useful & (since they ask for a yes or a no) are seldom asking for what the asker actually wants answered. It is unhelpful & unclear to ask 'A or B' when A & B are not mutually exclusive and/or not the only options. (And you may think they are when they are not.)  [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Comment: @philipxy Thnak you for edits, that are great! But I didn't understand you clearly. I mentioned which criterias I'm interested in. I'm stucked because I'm not DB architect so I don't know in which scenarios which option is better. I can't ask about third, forth ... options because I just don't know them because (as I mentioned but you removed it) I'm frontend developer so I don't know anything about DB architecture and it is my first time. When I tried to google this question, almost all questions was about "nested data vs flat data"

Comment: Your question is too general & vague & wide in scope & is unclearly an OR of parts (which merit closing) & shows no research effort at answering what you are asking (meriting downvotes) & even if you gave enough specific criteria & specifically how to balance them & how you were stuck deciding, ultimately this comes down to asking for an opinion, which is off-topic. Not all questions are on-topic. "What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question?" Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. [tour] [ask] [Help]

Comment: PS Look at the "answer" post: "it's hard to say anything conclusive". A "question" post evoking that response is not useful & an "answer" post containing is no answer & shouldn't be posted.

Comment: @philipxy  "What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question?" - if you mean what I tried to google before asking questions here then answer is exactly what I wrote in the title of this question. The one more thing which I tried is to ask ChatGPT but SO community has allergy to it so I didn't include AI answer in the text of question

Comment: With NoSQL databases the data structure is driven by the queries being run. There are no relationships in Firebase so you may need to denormalize the data for example. Also note there are no *DB's* per se. Firebase has parent nodes, child nodes and really, that's it. I get the gist but the faster you adopt the terminology the smoother the voyage will be - it's not SQL by any means. I will point you do this classic but applicable article [Denormalizing is Normal](https://firebase.blog/posts/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal). Write some code - then post a question when you get stuck.

Comment: You should really go through the [getting started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) as well - it's very helpful and answer a lot of questions. I always suggest starting with a very basic "To-Do" type application to get the feel for the SDK and working with an online first database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** use multiple databases for splitting the data like that. Just use a single database and model within that.

Honestly, aside from that it's hard to say anything conclusive, as the best data model for a NoSQL database depends mostly on the use-cases of your app. I often explain this as using a data model that closely matches what is shown in the screens of your app.

Start with a simple model for your first few use-cases, then evolve that as you add more use-cases that need additional data. Your initial model seems fine for a first stab, although I'd probably change the `chatsId` array to a `chatsId` map with the same keys and `true` as their value. For more on this, see [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

To learn more about data modeling, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s), and probably also [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) (which is for Firebase's other database, but has lots of great explanation of how to think of NoSQL data modeling too).

Comment: Can you please give a simple scenario when I need more than 1 DB in 1 application?

Comment: If you have more than 200k concurrent users, or have a load that is more than can be handled by one database. In those cases you'll want to shard the information in the way that is documented: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding. While it's good to consider a sharding strategy early on, it's probably best to wait until you have some experience with NoSQL data modeling and Realtime Database performance before doign so. In general, chat applications are not the hardest to scale - as they have natural shards in "chat rooms".